# How do i use opencv to measure an object height and width with a changing distance?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, geometry, augmented-reality

Im currently working on a code that is running on python where the idea of the code is to measure an object height and width accurately regardless of the distance of the camera from the object, meaning if the object has a height and width of 5cm by 5cm, the camera should still display that measurement regardless of the distance changing further or closer to it.

below is the code that I have tried and googling and looking through forums has said that some formula is needed but i cant seem to grasp the idea.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_object_dimensions(contour, reference_width, reference_distance):
    # Calculate the bounding box around the contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # Assuming the camera calibration is done, convert pixel dimensions to centimeters
    pixel_width = w
    pixel_height = h
    # You may need to calibrate these conversion factors based on your camera and setup
    width_cm = pixel_width * pixel_to_cm_width
    height_cm = pixel_height * pixel_to_cm_height

    # Calculate the current distance based on the reference width and current measured width
    current_distance = (reference_width * reference_distance) / width_cm

    return width_cm, height_cm, current_distance

# Camera setup
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # Use 0 for the default camera

# Calibration factors for converting pixel dimensions to centimeters
pixel_to_cm_width = 0.1  # Adjust based on your calibration
pixel_to_cm_height = 0.1  # Adjust based on your calibration

# Initial reference distance (distance at which the width measurement is accurate)
initial_reference_distance = 50.0  # Adjust based on your setup
reference_width = 10.0  # Adjust based on your setup

while True:
    # Capture a frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert the frame to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise and improve edge detection
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # Perform edge detection using Canny
    edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150)

    # Find contours in the edged image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Iterate over detected contours
    for contour in contours:
        # Ignore small contours
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 1000:
            # Draw a bounding box around the contour
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # Get object dimensions and current distance in centimeters
            width_cm, height_cm, current_distance = get_object_dimensions(contour, reference_width, initial_reference_distance)

            # Display the dimensions and current distance
            cv2.putText(frame, f'Width: {width_cm:.2f} cm', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f'Height: {height_cm:.2f} cm', (x, y + h + 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f'Distance: {current_distance:.2f} cm', (x, y + h + 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Object Detection and Measurement', frame)

    # Break the loop when 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the camera and close all windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the result is as shown below

[image: Result 1]
[image: Result 2]
[image: Result 3]

As shown in the results, even with the changing distance the height and width change as well, Any help or advice is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: we would appreciate *screenshots* rather than *photos of your screen*. taking a screenshot is a built-in operation in every operating system.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is impossible. You either need to know the distance to correctly get the dimensions of an object based on its angular size OR you need to know the size beforehand to know the distance from the object.
For example, the sun and the moon appear to be the same size in the sky, despite the sun being a few orders of magnitude bigger than the moon, it just happens to be a few orders of magnitude farther from Earth which means it ends up with the same angular size.

If you don't trust me, take a photo of something and calculate by hand what its dimensions are, using any method you want.

The formulas for angular distance are fairly well known and you can find them online.

Edit: this is also apparent in your code since you are trying to use "reference distance" and calculate "current distance" for each frame, which results in a build of errors (just leave the camera in a perfectly still position and leave it running for a while and observe the measured distance go all over the place, the same thing happens when using accelerometers and trying to find the position purely based on accelerometer data since the integration is not perfect and builds massive errors very quickly and this is why planes have expensive ring laser gyros and rely on other data like radar and a whole host of other devices to find their location).

Another big problem with your setup is that you're not creating a calibration matrix for your camera to deal with how it warps the image, but even with perfect calibration, your idea is still dead in the water because of the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: Ah thank you for your clarification, but I seem to have missed out some information out, i have a structure where the camera will be sitting in and I know the width and height of an object and I have a few set distances between the camera and the object, is it still possible? I just need it to scale the measurement between the distance.

Comment: @yong jie : If you know the size of the target object, what to do is just show it. No calculation needed.